# PowerBI is not passing over the datafield to the Python script

Tags: python, numpy, anaconda, powerbi-desktop

I am trying to run a simple Python script in PowerBI to get it working but it only comes up with many errors.I have tried to:

1. reinstall Numpy and Matplotlib.
2. tried using Python 3.5 and 3.6
3. Uninstall Conda and reinstall

I have a screen shot showing my issue (it all fits on one screen bellow). The data is just a,b,c and 1,2,3 for x and y labeled "Label" and "Data".

[Screen shot of error and code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ec4hd.jpg)

Code here:

```
# The following code to create a dataframe and remove duplicated rows is always executed and acts as 
a preamble for your script: 
dataset = pandas.DataFrame(Data, Label)
# dataset = dataset.drop_duplicates()

# Paste or type your script code here:

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
dataset.plot(kind='scatter', x='Label', y='Data', color='red')
plt.show()
```

Comment: The line "a preamble for your script:" is commented out in my script

Comment: have you commented out the dataset = pandas.DataFrame(Data, Label), then run it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to comment out the following:

```
dataset = pandas.DataFrame(Data, Label)
```

[image: Working example]

Even though it is 'commented out' it will run. It just sets up the data frame ready for the visual, here is a none working example, were it isn't commented out:

[image: None working Example]

Hope that helps